# How to not show HTML and CSS if a condition is true in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a login alert for my login page in my views:

```
<% if alert %>
<div class="row">
      <div class="card-panel blue lighten-4"><%= alert['message'] %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Even when the alert message is empty, the card-panel is still rendered with no text in it.

How do I make it so the card panel does not render at all if there is no message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
if alert
```

just checks if `alert` is anything other than `false` or `nil`. So if `alert` is a Hash then the test will always pass and you'll get an empty card.

If `alert` is always going to be a Hash, then you could say:

```
if alert['message'].present?
```

That will take care of the message being an empty string, a non-empty string, that contains only whitespace, the `'message'` key not being present in the `alert` Hash, etc.

If `alert` can be `nil` then you could say one of these:

```
if alert && alert['message'].present?

if alert.to_h['message'].present?

if alert&.fetch('message', nil)
```

`alert.to_h` gives you `alert` if `alert` is a Hash but gives you an empty Hash if `alert` is `nil`. `alert&.fetch('message', nil)` uses the safe navigation operator (`&.`) to hide the `nil` check and uses [`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) instead of the usual brackets to look up the key.

Comment: Thank you. Sort of figured it out a little bit after I saw your response but thanks for the help!